# Is encryption redundant if you are going to transport over SSL?

Tags: post, ssl, encryption

If I want to make a cross-domain ajax call to some method on another website in a POST and pass some data, is it redundant to encrypt the data if I am going to send it over SSL?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is redundant. SSL already encrypts with a very secret session key.

Comment: Is there  reason why someone might still encrypt even though they send over SSL? I can see encyrption used if storing data in a database, but not for encrypting something that is already encrypting.  Does encrypting it over SSL prevent man in the middle attacks?

Comment: SSL already prevents MITM attacks provided you use it correctly, that is to say provided you validate the peer identiy.